# Will I lose project functionality on upgrading QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.18, update, qgis-3

This might be a stupid question but if I update to QGIS 3.2.1 will I have problems working on projects created in my current 2.18.20?

Comment: It might be necessary to re-add some WMS services. I have not found the reason for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you won't have any issues. But still a lot of people have mentioned and even I have experienced that some of the features/tools work slowly in 3 version for example rendering or when the data is loaded from a network drive.